# UIAccelerometer and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiaccelerometer

I want to scroll a scrollview based on the UIAccelerometer values. What is the best way to accomplish this?

My main problem is that using the accelerometer values, I cannot set a content offset. Because the scrollview itself scrolls using a particular velocity and there are jerks happening when I try to scroll using accelerometer values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    if (sv.tracking || sv.decelerating) return;
    CGPoint pt = sv.contentOffset;
    pt.x += acceleration.x * 2;
    pt.y -= acceleration.y * 2;
    if (pt.x < 0) pt.x = 0;
    if (pt.x > sv.contentSize.width - sv.frame.size.width) pt.x = sv.contentSize.width - sv.frame.size.width;
    if (pt.y < 0) pt.y = 0;
    if (pt.y > sv.contentSize.height - sv.frame.size.height) pt.y = sv.contentSize.height - sv.frame.size.height;
    sv.contentOffset = pt;
}
```